# How to print out a diamant tag in XSLT transformation sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT sheet (more is written, but unimportant here):

```
<xsl:template name="conductorNames">
    <xsl:param name = "yValue" />
    <svg:text x="0" y="" text-anchor=""><xsl:value-of select="firstname" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="lastname" /></svg:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is, that within the `<svg:text x="0" y="".....` I want to print out the variable `yValue` as value for the text `y="$yValue"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is a "diamant tag"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this:

```
<svg:text y="{$yValue}"/>
```